how to ssr more than one string in a table at the same time
I would like to replace for more than one condition:
Example:
tab:([]a:`a`b`c;b:("abc-d";"rdf,e";"ertfg"))

update b:{ssr[x;"-"|",";" "]} each b from tab

I couldn't replace for both - and , at the same time, it can only take one.
I tried to join each both with b but it doesn't work well.

You can achieve this using over (/)
q)update ssr/[;("-";",");" "]each b from tab
a b
---------
a "abc d"
b "rdf e"
c "ertfg"


If replacing single characters with another avoiding ssr will perform much better as it is a slow operation.
q)update {@[x;where any x=/:"-,";:;" "]} each b from tab
a b
---------
a "abc d"
b "rdf e"
c "ertfg"

Similar but passing full column to = on each iteration. May perform better than first answer.
update @[;;:;" "]'[b;where each any ",-" =\:b] from tab
a b
---------
a "abc d"
b "rdf e"
c "ertfg"


You can use regex matching in ssr
q)update ssr[;"[-,]";" "]each b from tab
a b
---------
a "abc d"
b "rdf e"
c "ertfg"

See https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/
